# Is there a more efficient way of sorting an Array of titles than the way I'm doing it (without leading quotes or articles)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I know questions like this are here, but I'm specifically addressing processing speed. What I'm doing already works.

I have an Array containing titles to sort on. Some of the titles start with a double quote, such as `"You're in Charge" Leadership in Difficult Times` and some start with A, An, or The such as `A Collective Impact on Literacy`. I want to ignore those in sorting, and this works fine:

```
    theArray.sort(function(a, b) {
        var titleA = a.title.toLowerCase();
        titleA = removeCertainLeadingCharacters(titleA);
        var titleB = b.title.toLowerCase();
        titleB = removeCertainLeadingCharacters(titleB);
        return (titleA < titleB) ? -1 : (titleA > titleB) ? 1 : 0;
    });
```

where the function removeCertainLeadingCharacters() is defined this way:

```
function removeCertainLeadingCharacters(title) {
    // remove leading quote from a lowercase title, and also leading articles (a, the, an)
    if (title.indexOf('"') == 0) title = title.substr(1);
    words = title.split(" ");
    if(words[0] == 'a' || words[0] == 'the' || words[0] == 'an' ) {
        return words.splice(1).join(" ");   
    }
    else {
        return title;
    }
}
```

My only question is whether there is a faster way of doing this. If I'm sorting an Array of about 800 titles and leave out the call to removeCertainLeadingCharacter() the sort is blazingly fast. If I add the function call then it's slower. Not a huge drag on the speed, but noticeably slower. Without the call it's basically instantaneous.

So I was just wondering if there is a faster of accomplishing this than what I'm doing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may save you some time (50% of the time) because you do not need to split when you only check the first word in the statement.

```js
function removeCertainLeadingCharacters(title) {
  // remove leading quote from a lowercase title, and also leading articles (a, the, an)
  if (title.indexOf('"') === 0) {
    title = title.substr(1);
  }

  if (title.startsWith('a ')) {
    title = title.substring(2);
  } else if (title.startsWith('an ')) {
    title = title.substring(3);
  } else if (title.startsWith('the ')) {
    title = title.substring(4);
  }
  return title;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does seem somewhat faster. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the final line in your sort algorithm like this:

```
return titleA - titleB;
```

Comment: Interesting enough, that actually completely messed up the alphabetical sorting. After trying that change the sorting seemed basically random. When I restored the line I had the sorting worked again. I don't know why.

Comment: @DougLerner Weird! Your return line does the same thing this line does. It returns negative number if B is larger than A, positive if A is larger than B, and 0 if they are equal. That’s how most sort algorithms work.

Comment: But it's not really the same thing, is it? In my case I'm returning exactly -1, +1, or 0 with each comparison. With your expression, I'm returning some unknown large and small positive and negative numbers. Could that be affecting the overall comparisons?

Comment: @DougLerner The function only cares if the compareFunction result is negative, positive, or zero. See the description section here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Hmm... Can't explain what I'm seeing then. Weird.

Comment: It doesn't work because there's weird type conversion going on.  Comparing strings with the `<` and `>` operators may work (assuming that both strings are transformed to lowercase), but attempting to subtract one alpha string from another in JS will give you `NaN`.

Comment: I was thinking it must be something like that as well. Like when you compare dates, you can use > and < operators, but if you actually want to subtract two dates to get a difference you need to use something like the .getTime() method to first convert the date to an integer.